# By what criteria do we find out that fasttext unsupervised is well trained?

Tags: fasttext

I want to train unsupervised fasttext for word representation. To do this, I have install fasttext from [official website](https://fasttext.cc/), I read the [word representation](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html) page, and I used `model = fasttext.train_unsupervised()`, but it just show me the avg.loss.
My question is, how do I know my fasttext is trained well on my dataset or it is not trained well and I must change the hyperparameters.
I want use fasttext in my embedding layer for text generation. I need a method or some tips to evaluate my fasttext that trained unsupervised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no one 'best' set of word-vectors: it always depends on your data & downstream goals.

The 'loss' that's optimized, & reported, during `FastText` training is for the model's internal word-to-nearby-word goal. It *is* only a guide, via its overall trend & eventual inability to improve further, as to whether more of that kind of training can improve on that internal goal. It is *not* the case that a model that can reach a lower loss has better metaparameters, or is better at any real downstream tasks.

So: if reported loss was still noticeably decreasing from epoch to epoch when training stopped, it may be worth trying a longer run of more iterations, with all the other data/parameters the same, that instead reaches a point of no-further improvement ('convergence' of the underlying optimization). But don't use FastText-training loss to choose between models with different other metaparameters.

For that, you should use some other repeatable quantititave evaluation of the final word-vectors, ideally in a task as close as possible to your real usage. That is: really plug alternate versions of them into your next step, and review how well they work, & how different sets influence where the full system works better, or worse.

This might be very manual & ad hoc at first: running a set of familiar challenges, and merely 'eyeballing' whethere one 'seems to' be giving more desirable answers or not. But to do well, & truly search all the possibilities for data preprocessing & model metaparameters, you'd ideally want to use some large, automated, & potentially growing-over-time set of probes you can score as 'better' or 'worse'.

The automated tests used in original word-vector papers are often based on some task like analogy-solving, or matching a human's native language reports of which words should be 'closer' to each other than another. Sometimes it makes sense to try to re-use those, as interim evaluations, but ultimately what makes a word-vector perform best on those may not always be what works in other tasks. (In particular, I've seen where word-vectors worse at analogies work noticeably better as inputs to a classifier.)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your complete and comprehensive answer. I tried to adjust the hyperparameters suggested in https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html#advanced-readers-playing-with-the-parameters using several nested for-loop. And I noticed that when the number of my epochs increases the avg.loss decreases (from 2.286797 to 0.947587 ). Did I do the right thing? you suggest me do some repeatable quantitative evaluation, can you give me some website or article links for me to read and use in my work?

Comment: In general, you suggest that I only manipulate epochs and continue if it reduces avg.loss, but avg.loss is not a good criterion for setting other hyperparameters, and a model with more avg.loss may be better than a model with less avg.loss for my work. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes - use loss to judge whether more epochs may help. But to guide other tuning, you'll need a readout other than loss – ideally something as specific as possible to your end goals. ('Text generation' seems especially hard to review, but you could, for pairs of models, see what text is generated from different representative prompts – & have a human-in-the-loop reviewer pick which is 'better'. You might eventually find some metaparameter changes at the FT step tend to win more 'better' judgements downstream.)